# How to run a function exported from module.export in command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, export

I have code something like below in `test.js`

```
const run = async () => {
  //some code running
}
module.exports = {
  run,
};
```

Now how to call the `run` method from the command line?

Comment: Like `node -e "require('yourModule').run()"`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The module name should be the name in package.json or something else?

Comment: No, just the filename (`test` in your example), prepended by a directory path if needed: `require('./test').run()` or `require('some/other/dir/test').run()`